# Create a CloudKit record type programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, cloudkit

How do I programmatically create a record type in CloudKit, without doing it in the dashboard? For example: in the app that I am making, a user will create a group, let's call it "Cars". Then the user will add many different cars to that record type, like "Honda", "Toyota", and so on. How do I do this programmatically? I'm working in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing record types and record values. For your example you would want a `Car` record type, and then you would want a `Manufacturer` value in the record that is set to "Honda", "Toyota", etc.

You could also design this by creating a `Manufacturer` record type, creating one record for each manufacturer, and having a reference from the `Car` record to its `Manufacturer` record.

To create a new `Car` record just create a `CKRecord` object, set the properties you want, and save it to the server using `CKDatabase.saveRecord()`.

To answer the question in your title, record types are created for you automatically when you save a record to the development environment. You can not modify record types or schemas programmatically in the production environment.

You can read more about the development and production environments in the [CloudKit Quick Start Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EditingSchemesUsingCloudKitDashboard/EditingSchemesUsingCloudKitDashboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH5-DontLinkElementID_1).